# If $F$ is a filter on $X$, then $F$ is contained in an ultrafilter $U$.

Tags: set-theory, filters

So the original proof uses Zorn's lemma to find a maximal filter $U$ containing $F$, and then shows $U$ is an ultrafilter.

Edit: Let $P:=\{G\subset\mathbb{P}(X):F\subseteq G$ and $G$ is a filter$\}$.

By Zorn's lemma, let $G_m$ be a maximal filter in $P$. We claim $G_m$ is an ultrafilter:

Let $A\subset X$ be such that $A\notin G_m$. It suffices to show that $X\setminus A\in G_m$.
Let $G':=G_m\cup\{A\}$, then clearly $F\subseteq G'$. By maximality of $G_m$, $G'$ cannot be a filter. Hence $G'$ must violate at least one of the four conditions:

(1)$\emptyset\notin G'$, (2)$G'\neq\emptyset$, (3) for all $C,D\in G', C\cap D\in G'$, and (4) if $D$ is such that $C\subset D$ for some $C\in G'$, then $D\in G'$.

Now, (2) always holds because $G_m\subset G'$ and $G_m\neq\emptyset$.

If I can prove that $A=\emptyset$, then $X\setminus A=X\in G_m$ and we are done. But I don't know how to prove that $A$ is empty.

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(X)$ contains disjoint sets, so it can not be a filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not easy to show $U$ is an ultrafilter, since it is not an ultrafilter (unless $X$ has only one point).  Indeed, if $x,y\in X$ are two different points, then $\{x\},\{y\}\in U$ but their intersection is not in $U$.